# How to have special treatment on first emission of an Observable with a single Subscription

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have the following code:

```
this.obs$ = this.service.obs$;

this.obsSubscription = this.obs$.subscribe(
    (eltArray: Elt[]) => this.eltArray = eltArray
);

this.anotherObsSubscription =  this.obs$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
    (eltArray: Elt[]) => this.anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce = eltArray
);
```

Out of curiosity, but also in order to limit my number of subscriptions (that I have to unsubscribe to), I would like to know how I could achieve the same result with only one `Subscription`.

So I would like to initialize `anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce` on first emission of `this.service.obs$` and set `eltArray` on *every* emission of `this.service.obs$`.

Comment: I am aware of the existence of `take(1)` or `first()` operator, but would like to find a way to combine them with my subscription.
I am also aware that I could just use a boolean within my component indicating whether my list has been initialized but that is not really elegant, is it ?

Comment: Depending on your Observable, `this.obs$.pipe(take(1))` does not guarantee that you get the first emission of the Observable, also note that the first item emitted to each of your subscribers is not necessarily equal. 

Not sure whether either of those things matter for what you are doing, but worth thinking about.

Comment: And to me, a single subscription + boolean solution sounds pretty nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter with the scan operator.

```
this.obs$.pipe(
    scan((acc, value) => [acc[0]++, value], [0])
).subscribe(([count, eltArray]: [number, Elt[]]) => {
    if(count === 1) {
       this.anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce = eltArray;
    }
    this.eltArray = eltArray;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following -

```
anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce = null;

this.obs$.subscribe((eltArray: Elt[]) => {
      if(this.anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce === null) {
        this.anotherEltArrayOnlyChangedOnce = eltArray
      }

      this.eltArray = eltArray
    }
   )
```

Comment: It perfectly suits my need here : simple, quite elegant, and has the expected behavior. Thus, I upvoted the answer. However, I won't mark this as the accepted answer as it does not exactly answer "How to have special treatment on first emission of an Observable with a single Subscription" but rather "How to initialize value on first emission of an Observable in addition to standard treatment, with a single Subscription". Thanks a lot, though.